# Lucee <cfadmin> does not correctly store connectionString property when executing an "updateDatasource" operation

Tags: sql, datasource, cfml, lucee

I'm hoping someone can shed some light on this issue. I'm attempting to programmatically add datasources to the Lucee Server context (ie. not on a per-application basis, but rather datasources that are made available to all web contexts on the server). The following call to the  tag to create the datasource or later update the same datasource results in the connectionString never being saved correctly.

NOTE: "updateDatasource" will create a datasource if it doesn't already exist.

**Host Environment**: Windows Server 2019 running Lucee 5.3.8.206 on OpenJDK17.

**Database Environment**: Windows Server 2019 running SQL Server 2019.

```
<cfadmin
    action="updateDatasource"
    type="server"
    password="F4K31234"
    bundlename="org.lucee.mssql"
    bundleversion="8.4.1.jre8"
    classname="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver"
    dsn="my_new_datasource"
    name="my_new_datasource"
    newName="my_new_datasource"
    connectionString="jdbc:sqlserver://SQLSERVERNAME\MSSQLSERVER2019;DATABASENAME=my_database;sendStringParametersAsUnicode=true;SelectMethod=direct"
    dbusername="Temp1234"
    dbpassword="F4K31234"
    connectionLimit="100"
    alwaysSetTimeout="true"
    validate="false"
    allowed_select="true"
    allowed_insert="true"
    allowed_update="true"
    allowed_delete="true"
    allowed_create="true"
    allowed_revoke="true"
    allowed_alter="true"
    allowed_grant="true"
    clob="true"
    lineTimeout="60">
```

Every time this operation is attempted, the Connection String is stored as "my_database". In other words, it appears to ignore the string provided in the connectionString attribute and instead stores the database name for the datasource connection string.

These settings are exactly what I use when manually setting up a datasource in the Lucee Server administrative area (minus the obvious fake username, passwords, server names, and database names).

Before I go about filing a bug, I wanted to be sure I'm not missing something here. I appreciate any insight!

Comment: If it works in the Lucee Administrator, then it should work with cfadmin also, because the Lucee Administrator makes use of cfadmin to create or update the datasources. See: https://github.com/andreasRu/Lucee/blob/1950f49a6518cb6cbb88999a6c2a393585676b56/core/src/main/cfml/context/admin/services.datasource.create.cfm#L44 . Is only the connection string not beeing.updated? Are you sure you are using the right passwords (for server context) to change the settings?

Comment: Unfortunately, this is not the case. Based on the response from the Lucee development team, cfadmin is not an officially supported method for creating datasources outside of the administrative interface itself. You can see additional details here for why:

https://luceeserver.atlassian.net/browse/LDEV-3758

Comment: I will post an answer to my question once I have a working example, but I have found an alternative approach via the cfconfig plugin CLI for CommandBox.